# Invalid Submission Before setting up your app detail page...specify how your app integrates with Facebook

Tags: facebook

When I'm trying  to "Submit App Detail Page" I have this message

Invalid Submission
Before setting up your app detail page, you must specify how your app integrates with Facebook. Click here to vist your apps settings page to manage your integrations.

But If I Click on the link on the page 
For : Select how your app integrates with Facebook

> Website with Facebook Login **is checked and green.**

Anyone has this problem too ?

Comment: Can you show us the page/link/app you are having trouble with?

Comment: I found the solution in Edit Application select Category : Other ... not game

Comment: @ValentinAuvinet is that really the solution you used? I tried that and it doesn't let me submit either.